# can i have a second media.phtml in my magento new theme?

Tags: image, magento, media, php

so this is the project.

I need to display  the regular product images for most of the products but for a second set of products i need to replace the image with a javascript that will change depending on selections of options.

My question is: can i have two different media.phtml. Let's say media.phtml and js-media.phtml. And if i can where can i change this?

Or another case could be finding the file responsible for the content on the product page and change it there.

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

I thought i could change this creating a new layout file but apparently i am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally something you can do.

In your template create your `js-media.phtml` in `templates/catalog/product/view`.

Then if you want to assign this new template only to some of the products, you can switch media template straight from the backend of magento, through the `Design` tab of a product info.

There you can do this by adding a bit of XML into the `Custom Layout Update` field :

```
<reference name="product.info.media">
    <action method='setTemplate'><template>catalog/product/view/js-media.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```